# How do I delete and move later function arguments to the left if an object type is excluded?

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, arguments

I apologize if this has already been answered. I don't know a better technical term for this method and I can't seem to find here or Google searches.

Basically what I want is to be able to make a function like how jQuery handles Ajax function arguments. Example: `$.get(url, callback);` and `$.post(url, data, callback);`

Basically if `data` is excluded from the function it will move `callback` to the left in its place. Since when the function runs it uses the variable names from the input order. I presuming this method would involve checking the `arguments[1]` and `arguments[2]` but I want to make sure if this is the correct way since I like to have my code clean as possible.

Comment: Yes, check whether the third parameter is `undefined` and the second is a function, then you know that the user omitted the `data` argument not the `callback` one. But if you're looking for clean code, don't do such magic at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After spending time using the helpful information here. I managed to code up my solution. I'd thought I post my working (simplified edit) result for those that want a good example how to make one.

```
function post(url) {
    var callback, data, isAsync, // Prepare possible arguments.
        i, // Loop index.
        length = arguments.length; // Get arguments length.

    // Check the argument's types for optional passed parameter options.
    for (i = 1; i < length && i < 4; i++) {
        if (typeof arguments[i] === "object") {
            data = arguments[i];
        }
        if (typeof arguments[i] === "function") {
            callback = arguments[i];
        }
        if (typeof arguments[i] === "boolean") {
            isAsync = arguments[i];
        }
    }

    // Asynchronous is enabled by default.
    if (isAsync === undefined) {
        isAsync = true;
    }

    // More code here...
}
```

Comment: Why do you check `(data, callback and isAsinc ) === undefined` since you declare those variables and not initialize it, so this check is not useful, will ever be true. check if `arguments[i] === undefined ` or `arguments[i]`.

Comment: True, the idea was just in case the occurrence of the same type appears again and that the first time will be kept. I'll remove them now. Thanks. @JoseHermosillaRodrigo

Answer (score 1):

instead of checking for arguments[1] and arguments[2] , you should check

```
$.post(url, data, callback)
```

whether url is string, data is object , callback is function

Comment: Would you use `function get(url, arg1, arg2) {/*...*/}` or `function get(url) {/*arguments[1] and arguments[2]*/}` method?

Comment: function get(url) you can check the remaining with arguments