# JSLint Unexpected 'arguments'

Tags: javascript, node.js, arguments, jslint

Is there a JSLint comment that can be declared to ignore the warning? Also, why does it warn about the error? I recall reading somewhere they are not true arrays, so coders had to get the arguments length and pass the values by a for loop into an array for some reason.

This is one way I use arguments posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38193601/6318164). I also use it for `console.log` for perimeter passing tests.

Comment: Aside: there are alternatives to JSLint if you don't like Crockford's defaults, eg. ESLint, JSHint - these are very customisable and you can still enable the rules you actually like from JSLint.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know whether or not the warning can be ignored or exactly why Crockford doesn't like the arguments object, so this won't be a great answer.

Here's what I do know: ES6 provides the [rest parameter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/rest_parameters), which gives us a much cleaner way to get nearly the same functionality as with the arguments object (there are a few differences). Also, JSLint won't give you any warnings for it (unless you aren't assuming ES6).

For example, if you wanted to write a sum function, with the arguments object your code might look like this:

```
function sum() {
    const args = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 0);
    return args.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
}
```

With the rest parameter, you could write the sum function like this:

```
function sum(...args) {
    return args.reduce(function (a, b) {
        return a + b;
    });
}
```